Issue With 2d Noise
I'm making a top down survival game and I have done a procedural world gen using noise2D (FastNoiseLite). The next step was to randomize the seed, but I can't figure out how to...
Thanks
I tried :
@export var noise_height_text : NoiseTexture2D
var noise : Noise
[...]
seed = randi_range(0,9000000000)
noise.seed() = seed

and
@export var noise_height_text : NoiseTexture2D
[...]
seed = randi_range(0,9000000000)
noise_height_text.seed() = seed

Both gives me the error : Only identifier, attribute access, and subscription access can be used as assignment target.

The error message you're getting is telling you that you can't assign a value to a function call (assignment target cannot be seed()). Try accessing/assigning the noise object's seed property, like so: noise.seed = seed.

Ok I tried it and now it gives me a new error : Invalid set index 'seed' (on base: 'Nil') with value of type 'int' . I've tried to find a solution but It's not successful yet... I'll keep searching.
Thanks for your help

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/math/random_number_generation.html
